# error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors

I got

```
error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
```

when i try to compile my C++ project.

all error point me to vc++ files

```
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(32): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(120): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(133): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(256): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(279): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(375): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(474): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(486): error C2039: 'memcmp' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(486): error C3861: 'memcmp': identifier not found
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(491): error C2039: 'strlen' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(491): error C3861: 'strlen': identifier not found
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(511): error C2039: 'memchr' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(511): error C3861: 'memchr': identifier not found
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(522): error C2039: 'memset' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(522): error C3861: 'memset': identifier not found
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(568): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(571): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(574): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(577): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(580): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(583): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(586): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(589): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(592): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(596): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(600): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(604): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(608): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(611): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(614): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(617): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(622): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(625): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iosfwd(628): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\limits(80): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\limits(133): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\limits(139): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\limits(139): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
```

what are these errors and how i can solve them.'
these errors appear suddenly while before i never see these errors.

**in the project i am working on, i never *use extern C***

thanks

Comment: Are you using other libraries? It might be an error in one of their header files using `extern "C" {` and forgetting the closing `}`.

Answer (score 7):

This error happens when you include your header file inside `extern "C"`  command

```
extern "C"
{

    #include "Header.h"
}
```

just include `#include "cs.h"` outside `extern c` and you are good to go.

```
#include "Header.h"
extern "C"
{

    //code

}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to provide any help for you without showing your sources but info on [MSDN for error #2894](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95bhc9c2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and on [some other portals](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/101717/Error-C2894-templates-cannot-be-declared-to-have-C) is pretty straight forward:

```
// C2894.cpp
extern "C" {
   template<class T> class stack {};   // C2894 fail

   template<class T> void f(const T &aT) {}   // C2894
}
```

Maybe you have file named `.c` instead of `.cpp`, or switched some compilation flags.

Answer (score 2):

if you have written  this...

```
extern "C"
{
    #include "Header.h"
}
```

than write it as

```
extern "C++"
{
    #include "Header.h"
}
```

When you try to refer a C functions in C++ it will through error to avoid that you just quote it to C++ so that you can refer it in .CXX or .Cpp functions

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the reason is very simple: some file name(s) in your project are the same as in standard C/C++ library that is included in your project by default settings of VS.
For example, **string.h**. And this fact will spawn the error. Just rename such files and you will get success in building your project.